# Sum of x coordinate

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Suppose that three points on the parabola $y=x^2$ have property that their normal lines intersect at a common point (m,n) . We have to find The sum of their x coordinates .

I just  know equation of normal with three different slope woukd be $y=mx-2am-am^3$ .

Here a=1/4 and m is slope of normal .

but now how to proceed .

Comment: Slope of normal is just minus reciprocal of derivative of function so it's $-\frac{1}{2x}$

Comment: Better to recast the equation of the normal in terms of the parameter 't' corresponding to the feet of the normal

Comment: Just a start of an idea :N ote that once $2$ points have be chosen, the third is forced. Let first pick two points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$. The equation of the normal is $(i=1,2)$:
$$
y = -\frac{1}{2x_i}(x-x_i) + y_i
$$
Searching for the point of intersection $(m,n)$ :
$$
\begin{cases}
y = -\frac{1}{2x_1}(x-x_1) + x_1^2 \\
y = -\frac{1}{2x_2}(x-x_2) + x_2^2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Giving $(x,y) = (m,n) = (-2x_1x_2(x_1+x_2),\frac12 + x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2)$

Comment: Hint: Relate slopes with the x-coordinate. Now what does the sum of x-coordinates look like in terms of slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the normal at a point $(h,h^2)$ on the parabola passes through $(m,n)$. Then $$-1=\left(\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=h}\right)\left(\frac{h^2-n}{h-m}\right)=2h\left(\frac{h^2-n}{h-m}\right)$$
Therefore, $-(h-m)=2h^3-2nh$ and hence $2h^3-(2n-1)h-m=0$.

The $x$-coordinates of the three points are the three roots of the above cubic equation in $h$. So the sum of the $x$-coordinates is $0$.